# Open new screen when backend response is success

Tags: flutter, dart, rxdart

I have a SplashScreen that retrieve information from my Api. When response is success i would like open my second screen but I have a error because after my method to open new screen I need to add some return widget.

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: bloc.appInformation,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<AppInformationModel> snapshot){
          return onResponse(snapshot);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

My response method look like this.

```
  Widget onResponse(AsyncSnapshot<AppInformationModel> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      openMain();
      return Center(
        child: Text(
          snapshot.data.version,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30.0),
        ),
      );
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text('Error');
    }
    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
  }
```

And `openMain()` is just

```
      void openMain() {
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'home');
  }
```

My second screen work perfect.

The error is

> setstate or markneedsbuild called during build onTap

I understand is because my return widget is after opanNavigation() but i must return a view.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just put `return Center(...` inside of the `home` named route?

Comment: try wrapping the statement in a if(mount){} https://flutterbyexample.com/stateful-widget-lifecycle/#2-mounted-is-true